# How is Whatsapp delivering notifications?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I am having some [issues with Whatsapp notifications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54137/blocking-mode-not-working-with-whatsapp) and I'd like to better understand what's the root cause of the problem.

It seems that the application is somehow bypassing (at least partially) the system notification system.
In addition to ignoring Touchwiz blocking mode, the application works weirdly because its notifications do not turn off music volume when I receive them while listening to music, and it is able to manage by itself the led colors.

How can they do that from a technical point of view?

Is there any way to disable this behavior and have Whatsapp to entirely rely on system notification system and completely follow its rules?

Comment: I don't quite see what's the difference between this question and [your previous question on the same subject](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54137/12442). Could you clarify or explain?

Comment: You're right, I'm basically asking the very same thing. I created the two questions because in this one I wanted more technical details about how notifications works in general, while the other was intended to specifically address the blocking mode issue.
I agree that the two questions are almost identical so probably it would be a good idea to merge them or to delete one of them.